problem of expansion: mixing \tl_put_right:Nn \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \str_if_eq:nnT
I need some help to get this code work. I think i have a problem with expansion.
For each author i need to add (at right of his name) the index of his address. So, i need to extract the index of each item in the list of address: my idea is to do something like
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \my_address {\str_if_eq:nnT {#1} {##2} {##1} } }

but it's not soo easy.
MWE
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \my_authors
\seq_new:N \my_address

\RenewDocumentCommand \author { m }
    { \seq_put_left:Nn \my_authors {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand \address { m }
    { \seq_if_in:NnF \my_address {#1} { \seq_put_right:Nn \my_address {#1} }
      \int_compare:nF {\seq_count:N \my_address = 1}
      {
      \seq_pop_left:NN \my_authors \l_tmpa_tl
      %\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \my_address {\str_if_eq:nnT {#1} {##2} {##1} } }
      \seq_put_left:Ne \my_authors {\tl_use:N\l_tmpa_tl}
      } 
      }
\RenewDocumentCommand \maketitle { }
    {
      \begin{center}
      \Large\@title\vskip20pt
      \seq_reverse:N \my_authors
      \normalsize\seq_use:Nnnn \my_authors { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ~and~ }\vskip10pt
      \footnotesize\itshape\footnotesize\itshape\seq_use:Nn \my_address {\par}\vskip20pt
      \end{center}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\title{The title of this work}
\author{F. Author}
\address{Author's adresse 1}
\address{Author's adresse 2}
\address{Author's adresse 3}
\author{S. Author}
\address{Author's adresse 2}
\address{Author's adresse 3}
\author{T. Author}
\address{Author's adresse 1}
\address{Author's adresse 4}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

Here we go

\end{document}


Maybe your question could be more explicit.

@jlab question edited. Is it ok now?

Thanks, it's better.

Without compiling the code: I doubt that you want \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn …}; instead, you probably want \tl_put_right:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn …}

@MaxChernoff didn't work, thanks.

I would reverse the order of \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn and \tl_put_right:Nn
\NewDocumentCommand \address { m }
  {
    \seq_if_in:NnF \l__studentmaths_address_seq { #1 }
        { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__studentmaths_address_seq { #1 } }
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__studentmaths_authors_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__studentmaths_address_seq
      {
        \str_if_eq:nnT { #1 } { ##2 }
          {
            \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { $^{##1}$ }
          }
      }
    \seq_put_left:Ne \l__studentmaths_authors_seq { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
  }

(I removed the \int_compare:nF {\seq_count:N \my_address = 1} because I don't understand it's purpose).
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__studentmaths_authors_seq
\seq_new:N \l__studentmaths_address_seq

\RenewDocumentCommand \author { m }
  {
    \seq_put_left:Nn \l__studentmaths_authors_seq { #1 }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \address { m }
  {
    \seq_if_in:NnF \l__studentmaths_address_seq { #1 }
        { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__studentmaths_address_seq { #1 } }
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__studentmaths_authors_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__studentmaths_address_seq
      {
        \str_if_eq:nnT { #1 } { ##2 }
          {
            \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { $^{##1}$ }
          }
      }
    \seq_put_left:Ne \l__studentmaths_authors_seq { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
  }

\RenewDocumentCommand \maketitle { }
    {
      \begin{center}
        \Large
        \@title
        \vskip 20pt
        \seq_reverse:N \l__studentmaths_authors_seq
        \normalsize
        \seq_use:Nnnn \l__studentmaths_authors_seq { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ~and~ }
        \vskip10pt
        \footnotesize\itshape
        \seq_use:Nn \l__studentmaths_address_seq {\par}
        \vskip20pt
      \end{center}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\title{The title of this work}
\author{F. Author}
\address{Author's adresse 1}
\address{Author's adresse 2}
\address{Author's adresse 3}
\author{S. Author}
\address{Author's adresse 2}
\address{Author's adresse 3}
\author{T. Author}
\address{Author's adresse 1}
\address{Author's adresse 4}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

Here we go

\end{document}



Thank you very much. I'll give it a try now, i hop this help me.

Great, this is what i need.

@cfr sure, thank you.

great! thanks for editing. I'll delete some of these comments ;).

note that the answer I wrote to the question you linked handled the constant completely incorrectly. I think it is right now, but don't copy what I had before. (it is rare for a constant to be appropriate, but no excuse for getting it wrong.)
